# Gronwall’s inequality - Proving a part of Proof

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In one of the lectures, we discussed and proved Gronwall's Inequality and the professor mentioned a few consequences of it but he never proved or showed any of them. And there is one in particular, which I couldn't do it by myself.

If $$ \psi(t) \leq \alpha + \int_{0}^{t} (\beta * \psi(t) + \gamma)ds, t\in [0,T]$$
for given constants $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}, \beta \geq 0$, and $\gamma \in \mathbb{R}$, then
$$  \psi(t) \leq \alpha \exp(bt) + \frac{\gamma}{\beta}(\exp(t\beta) -1), t\in[0, T].$$

I was considering $ \tilde{\psi}(t) = \psi(t) + \frac{\gamma}{\beta} $. But I couldn´t go far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have
$$ \psi(t) +\frac\gamma\beta\leq \alpha +\frac\gamma\beta+ \int_{0}^{t} \beta \left(\psi(s) + \frac\gamma\beta\right)ds,\quad t\in [0,T].$$
So from Gronwall's lemma you get
$$ \psi(t) +\frac\gamma\beta\leq \left(\alpha +\frac\gamma\beta\right) e^{\beta t},\quad t\in [0,T],$$
which is equivalent to
$$ \psi(t) \leq \left(\alpha +\frac\gamma\beta\right) e^{\beta t}-\frac\gamma\beta=\alpha e^{\beta t}+\frac\gamma\beta(e^{\beta t}-1),\quad t\in [0,T].$$